# $(document).ready() function fires before the document actually loads in IE, any way to fix it?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, colorbox

I'm trying to apply colorbox to some links on a presentation page and I used $(document).ready() to set it up. The problem is that the function I define fires before the elements actually load (before anything is loaded actually). The following script is located right at the end of the head section in the file.

```
echo '
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
';

while($descr = mysql_fetch_array($res_descr)) {         

    echo '
    try {
    $j(".fer_'.$descr['SectiunePagina'].'").colorbox({inline:true, width:"70%", height:"60%", href:"#fer_'.$descr['SectiunePagina'].'"});
    }
    catch(error) {
    alert(error.message);
    }
    ';
}                      
echo '
});
</script> 
';
```

the error.message is `Object doesn't support property or method colorbox.` and upon further inspection it turned out that the elements weren't loaded when it fired.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the script include of colorbox is linked to before your above script is run.

Comment: My bet is that this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Move above code close to end-tag for body section instead of head section.

Answer (score 0):

Put your function between the window load function

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //function here
});
```

Comment: Tried. Ran a little later than ready but still not before the items loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have much to do with the positioning of your script. It's a timing issue.

**ColorBox depends on the DOM being loaded with its content** to operate properly.  That's a fundamental part of its design.

You'll have to work out how to load the content you want ColorBox to use into the DOM **before** Colorbox is called.  It looks like you are querying a db for content; that will have to complete beore you call ColorBox.  Perhaps there's a callback function you can use as part of the db call.

KJM

Comment: I understand all that but I can see the elements on the page when the first alert is displayed so it must be there. Also everything works a-ok for some reason if I activate developer tools in IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery 1.8.0, it might be a known bug; see < http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282 >.  Claims to now be fixed.